# LAN connecting to wamp homepage, not projects in www

Tags: apache, wamp, moodle

I have tried to setup wamp to host my projects and want to have them visible in my LAN. I have installed the newest version of wamp64 and am running moodle inside the www folder. On the pc it is running on I can connect to both the main wamp page and the moodle project.

Unfortunately on a laptop connected to the same network i cannot connect to the moodle project. Though I **can** connect to the wamp main page/homepage. I have changed the httpd-vhost.conf file to the following:

```
# Virtual Hosts
#
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName localhost
  ServerAlias localhost
  DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www"
  <Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/">
    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I assume this allows the laptop to connect to the wamp page but not yet to the moodle page/folder. Though I do not know how to give the laptop access.

Do I need to add another virtualhost for like the moodle project? 
Am kinda at a los here at this point.

The moodle has a config file that might possibly mess with it too. This is the file:

```
<?php  // Moodle configuration file

unset($CFG);
global $CFG;
$CFG = new stdClass();

$CFG->dbtype    = 'mariadb';
$CFG->dblibrary = 'native';
$CFG->dbhost    = 'localhost';
$CFG->dbname    = 'moodle';
$CFG->dbuser    = 'xxxx';
$CFG->dbpass    = 'xxxx';
$CFG->prefix    = 'mdl_';
$CFG->dboptions = array (
  'dbpersist' => 0,
  'dbport' => '',
  'dbsocket' => '',
  'dbcollation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
);

$CFG->wwwroot   = 'http://localhost/moodle';
$CFG->dataroot  = 'C:\\wamp64\\moodledata';
$CFG->admin     = 'admin';

$CFG->directorypermissions = 0777;

require_once(__DIR__ . '/lib/setup.php');

// There is no php closing tag in this file,
// it is intentional because it prevents trailing whitespace problems!
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you have setup the dir only for `localhost` requests.

What you can do is change the `ServerAlias` to your LAN ip or to the address you are requesting from your browser
ex:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName localhost
   ServerAlias 192.168.1.3
   DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www"
   <Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/">
     Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
     AllowOverride All
     Require all granted
   </Directory>
 </VirtualHost>
```

What this does it is says that if apache gets a request for the `192.168.1.3` or whatever your `ServerAlias` entry is, it will treat it same way it would treat a `localhost` request.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!. Greatly appreciated. Unfortunately this does not fix my issue. When I type in the ip adress of my pc, on my laptop the WAMP page shows. BUt when i try and use the moodle page it refuses to load and the adress bar changes to "localhost/moodle" with the error connection refused.

Comment: Apologies it did. Screwed up somewhere else but what you did fixed it i think.

Comment: You may run into multiple issues when using fixed addresses. Logically though, your php files should not have any issue, since they run on the server, which should see everything as localhost. Maybe something in your code refreshes the page to the default Server Address?

Comment: Yeah it worked this afternoon. Will need to set it up on a different system. Lets hope it goes smoother there. Thanks atleast!